# networking a virtual machine from another on the same host?

Tags: networking

I am trying to connect 2 virtual machines on the same host. Basically trying to ping from one to another. How can it be done if both have same IP address?

edit:
I am currently using hping3 to learn about Denial of service Syn flood. So can the 2 VMs be used for this?

Comment: It would be allowed if there is some *virtual* network, with [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they share the same IP address this isn't possible. Ping uses ICMP echo requests and replies and ICMP doesn't use ports that could be NATted to different machine.

You'll need to bridge the vNIC to the local network so each VM gets a different IP. Alternatively, you could connect both to an internal, entirely virtual network - depending on what the hypervisor can be configured to do.

Comment: currently, I am trying to do a denial of service on both VMs for an educational purpose. but it is disabled. I am a newbie in networking. So I could get some insights on this. :(

Comment: You'll probably find that virtual network do not behave exactly like physical networks. This is in part due to limitations of the hypervisor and at the same time a much better insight into (the virtual part of) the network than a normal switch or router might have.